# How to capture all wireless network traffic wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I' using **wireshark 2.2.3**, I want to capture all wireless network traffic using **wireshark**.

I've tried from wireshark with:

> Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> IEEE 802.11 -> New -> wpa-psk

and in the Key box: "**AP:password**", But I get an **Invalid key format error**.

I don't find to set the promiscuous mode.

Promiscuous mode setting - trying both on and off in monitor mode.

Any body please help to get the wireless network traffic to get my all the request to capture to my team members in the same network.

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 promisc
[sudo] password for tb-desktop2: 
tb-desktop2@tbdesktop2:~$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1492 0    117205      0      0 0         96232      0      0      0 BMPRU
lo        65536 0    156470      0      0 0        156470      0      0      0 LRU
```

How to enable monitor mode mon0?

```
 sudo airmon-ng start wlan0


Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
1081    NetworkManager
1090    avahi-daemon
1107    avahi-daemon
1317    wpa_supplicant
1853    dhclient
Process with PID 1853 (dhclient) is running on interface wlp6s0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp6s0      Atheros AR9565  ath9k - [phy0]
```

Still I didn't get the network packets.

Comment: Try searching and posting in [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) also.

Answer (score 0):

*in the Key box: "AP:password", But I get an Invalid key format error.*

If you're trying to enter a password, you need to select wpa-pwd, not wpa-psk.  You may also wish to display the Wireless Toolbar via `View -> Wireless Toolbar`.  You can add decryption keys from the toolbar using `Decryption Keys... -> New -> Type:WPA-PWD, Passphrase:TBD,SSID:TBD`.

If you have an adaptor that integrates with Wireshark, such as an AirPcap adaptor, you can set the Wireless Settings from the toolbar as well.

You can enable promiscuous mode by double-clicking the applicable interface in the main Wireshark page's interface list or through `Capture -> Interfaces -> Options` or from `Preferences -> Capture -> Interfaces: Edit...`.

All that aside, I'm not sure you'll necessarily be able to capture what you want without enabling monitor mode.  I would recommend visiting the Wireshark [WLAN (IEEE 802.11) capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) wiki page and reading the information available there.

Comment: Excuse me still I didn't get the wireless network traffic please help me

Comment: naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ airmon-ng start wlan0 11
Run it as root
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ airodump-ng -c 11 wlan0
socket(PF_PACKET) failed: Operation not permitted
This program requires root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the traffic just set your antenna in monitor mode, *Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> IEEE 802.11* is to decrypt traffic, which is another subject.

Type `sudo airmon-ng check` to check which processes might cause trouble to set your antenna in monitor mode. (You got five in the example you showed).

To kill these processes you can do it manually with `kill <Process ID>` or you can type `sudo airmon-ng check kill`

And once everything seems clear, type again `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`. To verify if it worked you can check with `iwconfig` and in `wlan0` or `wlan0mon` MODE should say MONITOR.

There your antenna will capture ALL wireless traffic on the channel it is and you can see that through Wireshark.